# How to deploy/distribute vue project as desktop app

Tags: javascript, web, vuejs2, electron, desktop

I have a project made in VueJS. I've started from `vue cli` and almost finished the code. By `npm run build` I've created `/dist` folder with *static* folder and *index.html*. Now what I want is to convert **web app** into **desktop app**. It seems *electron* is what I need. However, after searching for instructions here and there, I'm not able to figure out where to start.

Answer (score 4):

some of the things I've used in the past...

- nw.js  https://nwjs.io/
- electron https://electron.atom.io/
- zeit-pkg  https://github.com/zeit/pkg
- nexe  https://github.com/nexe/nexe

there are others out there, but I'd say that pkg was the easiest to use for creating a single executable, but it creates the largest files. Nexe is a bit more work to setup depending on your dependencies. nwjs and electron have a slightly more complex setup as-well, compared to a single compile command, but they do give you more options.

Answer (score 2):

I have used electron to make a desktop app. (https://electron.atom.io/)

Please follow the steps for basic setup with electron :

1)  install electron globally using command

```
npm install electron -g
```

2) Add this in your package.json

Make **app.js** as a entry file

**package.json**

```
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "electron ."
 },
"bin" : "./bin/my-bin.js"
```

3) **app.js**

```
// Electron Desktop app

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let win;

function createWindow() {

win = new BrowserWindow({ icon: __dirname + '/images/brw.PNG', show: false 
})
win.maximize()
win.show()

win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), //path to your index.html
    protocol: false,
    slashes: true
}));

win.webContents.openDevTools();

win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null;
});

}



app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

4) Add **my-bin.js** in app/my-bin.js directory

**bin/my-bin.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var join = require('path').join
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var args = process.argv.slice(2);

 args.unshift(__dirname + '/../'); 

childProcess.exec('npm start', (err, stdout) => {
if (err) console.log(err);
console.log(stdout);
})
```

5) Then, in current working directory,

Execute

```
npm start
```

Yay, It will open your desktop application window.

Cheers !!

**Note** : You can develop this without "bin" entry in package.json, but if you would wish to package your app usig zeit/pkg, you will need it since it reads from bin entry.

pkg is used to make distribute executable's,where we can make executable's without source code.(hidden source code). But currently there is an issue for distributing electron app with pkg https://github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/52